# IMGLIB into yocto

Tags: yocto

I need to run C++ algorithm on gumstix using DSP image library. Without DSP, Algorithm is eating up 85% cpu with 20fps. I am trying to get TI Image Library IMGLIB on Gumstix with Yocto Project. I could not find any resources or hints how to do it.

It would be great if I can get some inputs on how to proceed with getting imglib on gumstix using yocto project/open-embedded

Should I write a recipe with bitbake or is there any other way to get IMGLIB on Gumstix?
am working on Linux
plz provide me the steps how to add IMGLIB into yocto..
am new to this plz help me regarding this.

Comment: there seems to be a **meta-ti** layer which has already a recipe for the library.

Comment: i want to use DSP for image processing application so am using IMGLIB for DSP whether i want to modify my code or it will IMGLIB automatically....everything am running on Yocto

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned meta-ti seems to have what you need[1]

[1] http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ti/tree/recipes-ti/imglib/imglib-c66x_3.1.1.0.bb?h=master